# Import Error in __init__.py when trying to have multiple test files in a folder

Tags: python, django

I'm unable to import my test files within a test folder in the Django app. I get a import error when I try to run `python manage.py test` (see picture below):

My project structure looks like this:

```
Blog
 -- migrations
 -- static
 -- templates
 -- tests
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- test_views.py
   |-- test_forms.py
   |-- test_models.py
 -- __init__.py
 -- admin.py
 -- apps.py
 -- forms.py
 -- models.py
 -- urls.py
 -- views.py
```

The **__init__.py** in the tests folder is this:

```
from test_views import *
```

[image: Python Import Error]

I appreciate your help and if anyone could link me to a good django project that I could use as a reference it would be super helpful!

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Post 1.6, there is no need to import `test_views` in `__init__.py ` file. Django will automatically run any file with name like - `test*.py`

Comment: Wow, all this time spent looking for a fix and I didn't notice that, I am using version 1.9. Thank you so much!